# Parsing data in Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have columns in Snowflake that appear to be a list of strings (ex. ["Apple", "Banana"]). I obtained them from an API whose raw form I applied JSON.stringify() to.

I am now hoping to format the columns so that they are a string of comma separated values without quotation marks (ex. Apple, Banana). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to consider loading the JSON directly without stringify() and then use Snowflake's SQL to parse the JSON to get the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your table looks as below

```
create or replace table fruits_table
(
  src variant
)
as
select parse_json(column1) as src
from values
('{"fruits":["Apple", "Banana"]}');
```

[image]

To remove the "" and retrieve the fruits you can run the query as below

```
select concat(src:fruits[0]::string,',',src:fruits[1]) from fruits_table;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use ARRAY_TO_STRING function:

```
create or replace table temp_table( v variant )
as
select parse_json($1) from values
('{"my_array_name":["Apple", "Banana"]}');


select ARRAY_TO_STRING( v:my_array_name,',') from temp_table;


+---------------------------------------+
| ARRAY_TO_STRING( V:MY_ARRAY_NAME,',') |
+---------------------------------------+
| Apple,Banana                          |
+---------------------------------------+
```